# OSX: Grammarian won't uninstall

Tags: software-installation, osx, rm

Im trying to uninstall an annoying app on my Mac called Grammarian Pro X and the uninstaller doesn't work with my version of OSX 10.11. You can uninstall the main app but there is still bits of the app left in Volumes/Grammarian PRO2 X/Grammarian PRO2 X/ and these can't be removed even with "sudo rm -Rf Volumes"; volumes being the parent directory of all the files associated with grammarian. Ive also tried to remove volumes but that just says "Read-only file system" and "directory not empty"???? What do I do to remove it????

Comment: Please exercise some common sense. If the system is read-only, it can't be modified, which includes removing files. Also, please see [this help section](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how to formulate your questions better.

Comment: I think OSX blocks `sudo rm -Rf /Volumes`, but `sudo rm -Rf '/Volumes/Grammarian PRO2 X'` should work.

Comment: While your question is on-topic here, you may be running into Mac-specific issues. If so, you'll find more expertise on [apple.se]. If you want to ask there, please don't just repost: either flag your question and request a migration, or delete your question here and repost there.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem in /Volumes that you mention is the installation virtual disk (dmg). Hence why it is read only. Umount/Eject it and it will be gone.

You can do it via the graphical interface or via:

```
sudo diskutil umount '/Volumes/Grammarian PRO2 X'
```

Be also careful what you do with the /Volumes directory, because it is the root of all your mounted filesystems, including the disk(s) where your OS, applications and data live.